# How to implement asynchronous parallel task executions with degree of parallelism constant across multiple concurrent requests?

Tags: c#, async-await, concurrency, task-parallel-library, .net-4.8

My API takes a collection of items (of different types) that need to be processed.

```
public class Collection
{
   public List<ItemType1> Type1Items {get; set;}
   public List<ItemType2> Type2Items {get; set;}
   public List<ItemType3> Type3Items {get; set;}
   public List<ItemType4> Type4Items {get; set;}
   .
   .
   .
}
```

The request handler passes on this `Collection` to `ItemsProcesser`. `ItemsProcessor` further divides the collection (based on the type) and calls an external API on each group. For instance, one incoming request with a collection containing items of 4 different types gets broken down into four collections having items of a particular type, leading to 4 external API calls.

So basically, the `Collection` type is used to represent an instance with multiple types as well as broken down instances containing items of specific types as well.

A collection in the incoming request can have items belonging to up to 20 different types. So my processing can involve anywhere between 1 to 20 downstream API calls for **each** incoming request. I want to execute these downstream requests in parallel to reduce the response time of the incoming request.

```
/// CollectionHandler.cs
public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var request = context.Request;
    var collectionToProcess = GetCollection(request);
    var processor = new ItemsProcessor()
    await processor.ExecuteAsync(collectionToProcess);
}
```

```
/// ItemsProcessor.cs
public async Task ExecuteAsync(Collection collection)
{
    foreach(var (typeName, collection) in collection.GroupByTypes())
    {
       await downstreamClient.ExecuteAsync(collection, type);
    }
}
```

```
/// ApiClient.cs
public async Task ExecuteAsync(Collection collection, string collectionType)
{
    // Validate that the collection input parameter
    // only has items of type name collectionType
    var isValid = collection.Validate(collectionType);
    if (!isValid)
    {
       throw new ValidationFailedException();
    }

    // Use collection in request body and
    // collection type as request parameter.
    var restRequest = GetRequest(collection, type);
    await restClient.ExecuteTaskAsync(restRequest);
}
```

Implementing asynchronous parallel for each isn't a big deal. But, even if that implementation has a degree of parallelism or throttling supported, multiple concurrent incoming requests would invoke `ItemsProcessor` in parallel and each of them fans out multiple downstream API calls.

How can I ensure no matter how many concurrent incoming calls, the number of parallel calls to downstream service doesn't cross a certain maximum limit?

Comment: Is `ItemsProcessor`a Singleton Service? If so, you could maybe use a [`SempahoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-6.0) or something like that.

Comment: The name `Type1Items` is repeated four times in the code sample. Is this intentional or it's an error?

Comment: Regarding the downstream API calls, are these synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: @Fildor, ```ItemsProcessor``` is not a singleton. It's instantiated for every request.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, my bad.. I've corrected the property names. The external API calls are asynchronous.

Comment: Could you include in the question a minimal/sketchy demo of how you use an `ItemsProcesser` to process a `Collection`?

Comment: By *"constant degree of parallelism"*, do you actually mean "maximum degree of parallelism"? It should be difficult to enforce a *constant* number of requests to the downstream service, if for example you don't have any incoming request!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, I meant max parallel downstream calls. Don't want an exponential rise in downstream calls due to parallel incoming requests. Also added a few extra code snippets.

Comment: What is the desirable behavior in case the incoming requests are so many, that satisfying them would violate the maximum degree of parallelism policy? Is it to queue the extraneous requests and fulfill them in a FIFO basis (potentially with an ever increasing latency), or to deny serving them immediately with an error message?

Comment: Also is it acceptable to solve this problem with a third-party library, like the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library, or it must be solved exclusively with built-in tools?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, FIFO is the approach. If latency increases too much, the degree of parallelism would've to be increased. Polly is for configuring retry policies right?. To give a bit of context, the external API used to support the collection of all types. The recent version is type-specific. So client needs to send collection with just 1 type of items. So, one external call is now getting replaced by anywhere between 1- 20 calls significantly increasing our service's API latency. I'm exploring how to parallelize the external calls and bring down the latency to around what it was earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the [`Bulkhead`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#bulkhead) policy from the [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) library:

```
using Polly;
```

```
private static IAsyncPolicy _policy = Policy.BulkheadAsync(
    maxParallelization: 20, maxQueuingActions: Int32.MaxValue);
```

- The `maxParallelization` is the maximum number of actions that may be executed concurrently through the policy.
- The `maxQueuingActions` is the maximum number of actions that can be queued, waiting for an execution slot, when the previous limit has been reached. Beyond this limit, a `BulkheadRejectedException` is thrown.

Then replace this line:

```
await processor.ExecuteAsync(collectionToProcess);
```

...with this:

```
await _policy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    await processor.ExecuteAsync(collectionToProcess);
});
```

As long as your service is running on a single process, the policy will be enforced.

Comment: This looks promising. I'm not sure if my service runs on a single process. If that's the case, then this implementation is cleaner.